# How to iterate through s3 files and write all txt files to a csv file separated by its run date(year)

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, aws-cli

Basically, I want to iterate through the bucket and use the folders structure to classify each file by its run date(year).

So, I have an s3 bucket that path essential looks like:

```
file/archive/run=2017-10-07-06-13-21/folder_paths/version=1-0-0/part-00000-b.txt

file/archive/run=2018-11-07-06-13-21/folder_paths/version=1-0-0/part-00000-c.txt
```

In the archive folder, it has the run dates in them.

Ultimately, I want to be able to iterate of the files, and write the part-000....txt files to a csv file by date(year). So I want all the .txt files that runs are in 2018 in one csv file, all .txt files in 2017, and all .txt files that are in 2019.

I am new to boto3 and s3 so I am pretty confused on how to go about doing this:

Here is my code so far:

```
#Import boto3 module
import boto3
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

#This is to List existing Buckets for the AWS account

PREFIX = 'shredded/'

#Create a session to your AWS account

s3client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    region_name=REGION_NAME,
)


bucket = 'mybucket'
startAfter = '2020-00-00-00-00-00'

s3objects= s3client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, StartAfter=startAfter )
for object in s3objects['Contents']:
    print(object['Key'])
```

Any suggestions or ideas would help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is something like this:

```py
2017_files = [object for object in s3objects['Contents'] if 'run=2017' in object]
2018_files = [object for object in s3objects['Contents'] if 'run=2018' in object]
2019_files = [object for object in s3objects['Contents'] if 'run=2019' in object]
```

This will check for all the items in the array `s3objects['Contents']` if it matches the string condition `run={year}`.

So then each of the variables i.e. `2017_files`, `2018_files` & `2019_files` would contain all the relevant paths.

From there, you could split the string by `/` and get the last split which would be `part-00000-b.txt` as an example.

To write to a `.csv`, check out Python's `csv` library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and how to use that, it's pretty solid.

Post back with how you go!